# Probability problem related to Markov inequality

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions

**Problem**

Let $p$ be the probability of a person chosen at random to support Bernie Sanders. A sample is taken of $50$ persons chosen at random, each of them is asked if he or she would vote for Sanders and $p$ is estimated from the relative frequence $$Y_{50}=\frac{\text{number of persons in favor}}{50}$$

a) Find an upper bound for $P(|Y_{50}-p|>0,1)$ that doesn't depend on $p$.

b) Find $n$ such that $P(|Y_n-p|>0,1) \leq 0,01$

**Attempt at a solution**

a) I've defined $Y_i=1$ if the $ith$ person supports Bernie, $Y_i=0$ if not. Then, for $i=1,...,50$, $Y_i \sim Ber(p)$. So $Y_{50}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{50} Y_i}{50}$

$EY_{50}=EY=p$, where $Y \sim Be(p)$.

I thought of using Markov inequality to get the upper bound $$P(|Y_{50}-p| \geq 0,1) \leq \frac{V(Y_{50})}{(0,1)^2}$$ $$=\frac{100(p(1-p))}{50}$$$$2p(1-p)$$

The problem is that this upper bound DOES depende on $p$, so I don't know what to do next to find the appropiate bound. The same goes for $b$ since in this case $n$ would also be in terms of $p$ if I cannot find an upper bound that is independent of $p$.

I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Prove that $p(1-p)\le \frac14$.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, if $0 \leq p < \frac{1}{4}$, then $\dfrac{3}{4} < 1-p \leq 1$, so $p(1-p) \leq \frac{1}{4}$. If $\dfrac{1}{4} \leq p \leq 1$, then $0 \leq 1-p \leq \frac{3}{4}$, so the upper bound I get is $p(1-p) \leq \dfrac{3}{4}$, is this correct? I mean, I got a higher value than yours. I am not sure if $\dfrac{1}{4}$ is the minimum  upper bound so that's why you've suggested that number.

Comment: Consider the minimum of $(p-\frac12)^2$ and what this implies when you expand it

Comment: @Henry Yes, in that particular case we would get equality, but I would like to show that for any value of $0 \leq p \leq 1$, $p(1-p) \leq \frac{1}{4}$. I could arrive to the upper bound $\frac{3}{4}$, but then I would get $P(|Y_{50}-p| \geq 0,1) \leq \frac{3}{2}$, which isn't of any help since we know that beforehand (probability functions take values between $0$ and $1$).

Comment: @Henry, sorry I read your previous comment, now I'll take your new suggestion into account.

Comment: $(p-\frac12)^2 = \frac14 -p+p^2 = \frac14-p(1-p)$

Comment: Thanks for your help, the minimum is $0$ and it attains this value at $p=\frac{1}{2}$ as you've said in a deleted comment, from the definition of minimum value of a function, it follows $\frac{1}{4}-p(1-p) \geq 0$.